# Error importing database with data

Tags: magento-1.9, database, error

When you try to import the database, the following message occurs:
[db error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dzQ20.png)

help me.

Comment: please mark answer if useful so others get solution on issue

Answer (score 0):

**Import database use command line. By using this method full database will import without error.**

Replace

- username with your Database Username.
  databsase_name with your Database Name

  **Paste this command with your credentional**
  mysql  -u username -p database_name  >  database.sql

  then paste password.
  ......

Comment: Hello, Mark my answer

Answer (score 0):

I think your exported database backup is corrupted. Have you checked the DB backup file by opening in any text editor?

Sometimes, while exporting the database from phpMyAdmin, you get wrong format of file and it contains HTML tags.

In order to get correct database backup, you need to first export it using command line. Use the following command to export the database from origin server:

> mysqldump -u username -p databasename > dumpfilename.sql

then provide the database login password when prompted.

To import the database using command line, use the following command:

> cd [path to database backup file]
>
> mysql -u username -p databasename < dumpfilename.sql

then provide the database login password when prompted.

Comment: @VandersondeCastro, please upvote my answer if it helped, so that it can build trust for other users that answer is correct.